# How to create a new Salesforce `Site` using API/DML

Tags: apex, site.com

I have some APEX code that is testing some business logic that relies on a specific `Site` defined in our organization. I would like to create this `Site` in the test logic so that I can make the test independent from the organization's data but [it seems that this object is read-only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_public_access_settings.htm). I have assigned the `CustomizeApplication` and `ManageCustomPermissions` permissions to my user but I still cannot create a `Site` by simply inserting the object in the DB, error:

```
entity type cannot be inserted: Site
```

I can understand the reason behind it since these Sites create publicly accessible urls for the organization. However, does anybody know of a workaround?

Comment: If you can share a snippet of code that you are trying to achieve test code for, it would help to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use the [Stub Provider Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) and mock the response you need.

You will first isolate your logic that queries for Site Object into its own class. Next, implement a Stab provider for that class. This way when tests run your actual method is stubbed and a mock response is returned.

Comment: Got it, I was wondering if there was a way to create real Site objects but I guess not.